# Swift : Adding Image in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextview

I am adding image in `UITextView` like this :

```
let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "myphoto.jpg"))
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, image.frame.width, image.frame.height))
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [path]
textView.addSubview(image)
```

This image overwritten in textview and my text does not appear because of the image. Image must be in textview line and i can write before and after the image. What should I do?

---

Here is a snapshot:

[image: Screen snapshot]

Comment: What do you mean by "image overwritten in textview and my text does not appear"? Maybe you can upload snapshot somewhere where we can see what you mean. I tried the above and it worked fine.

Comment: Incidentally, what is `image.frame` and what is `textView.frame`? Is the image view small enough to fit within the `textView`? You can log `NSStringFromCGRect(image.frame)` and for `textView`, too...

Comment: I tried another image and it worked somehow. but still i can't write before and after image. By the way i think image.frame is to set an original width and height. I don't know exactly. And here is my sample snapshot : [link](http://tinypic.com/r/34pjats/8)

Comment: "I think `image.frame` is set to ...". Hmm. I wouldn't guess what the `frame` is, but `NSLog` it or examine it in the debugger. Another image worked? "I still can't write before and after image". Hmm. Well, you certainly can't write before because you've put it at 0,0. You should be able to write after it, though.

Comment: Ok, i got it. I changed the 0,0 but still can't write before the image ? what is the problem ?

Comment: No, you're not going to be able to enter before it. All that `exclusionPaths` does is specifies that text cannot be displayed within that path. But the image is not part of the text that you entered there. You're just entering text and you told it to wrap around the coordinates specified by that path you provided.

Comment: So, what should i do ? Can you suggest another way for my purpose ? You know what i want now. Maybe you have a solution for that.

Comment: Do you want to be able to edit text and image together, moving the image as you enter text?!? No, there are no easy solutions to that problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway.Now i know this code doesn't work for me and my purpose.

Comment: This question maybe work for me : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429488/adding-images-overwrite-my-text-in-uitextview)  . You should check it out @Rob .